# AngularJS: Placeholder for <select> inside ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to add the placeholder inside html select tag in ng-repeat for angularJS application.

[Link to JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dh6cL2tp/)

My HTML looks something like

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="product">Product</label>
     <select class="form-control" ng-model="item.product"  ng-options="product as product.name for product in products"  plceholder="Select">        
     <option value="" disabled selected>placeholder</option>
     <!-- tried adding the above following line but it wont get added -->
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

and the controller has this

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.items=[{name: "item1"},{name: "item2"},{name: "item3"}];
    $scope.products = [{name: "product2", quantity: 2}, {name: "product1", quantity: 2}, {name: "product3", quantity: 2}];

}
```

I tried adding the option value but it wont get added. 
Can any of you guide me on how to approach this solution

Comment: Anyways you can suggest to add a placeholder?

Comment: any other solution is possible just to put the placeholder ?

Comment: reviewing your code, I stand corrected;  my statements were false, but now I have different questions, since your example appears to use AngularJs 1.0.3, published in November, 2012.  Hopefully this isn't really the version of angular you are using, or you have more problems than just the placeholder value....

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<option value="">Please select your option</option>
```